# How can I add onmessage handling to a subclass of WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to subclass WebSocket so that all traffic coming and going can be JSON-ified on the fly. This is to handle signaling for WebRTC, and will probably be useful in a bunch of other contexts.

Send poses no problem, but I have a hard time to figure how to make assigning events to onmessage (which can then work for other events too, I imagine).

This is how far I got:

```
class SignalingChannel extends WebSocket {
     send(m){
          super.send(JSON.stringify(m));
     }

     set onmessage(f) {
          // something probably goes in here
          // because this work ok but doesn't JSON-ify
          super.onmessage = f;
     } 
}
```

I tried reading up about function composition and currying but I can't see how to implement that in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this, maybe it can help someone looking to achieve this

```
// proxy the window.WebSocket object
  var WebSocketProxy = new Proxy(window.WebSocket, {
    construct: function (target, args) {

      const instance = window.socket = new target(...args);
      // WebSocket "onopen" handler
      const openHandler = (event) => {
        // console.log('Open', event);

      };

      // WebSocket "onmessage" handler
      const messageHandler = (event) => {

      };

      // WebSocket "onclose" handler
      const closeHandler = (event) => {
        // console.log('Close', event);

        // remove event listeners
        instance.removeEventListener('open', openHandler);
        instance.removeEventListener('message', messageHandler);
        instance.removeEventListener('close', closeHandler);
      };

      // add event listeners
      instance.addEventListener('open', openHandler);
      instance.addEventListener('message', messageHandler);
      instance.addEventListener('close', closeHandler);

      // proxy the WebSocket.send() function
      const sendProxy = new Proxy(instance.send, {
        apply: function (target, thisArg, args) {
          console.log(thisArg, args);
          target.apply(thisArg, args);
        }
      });

      // replace the native send function with the proxy
      instance.send = sendProxy;
      // return the WebSocket instance
      return instance;
    }
  });

    // replace the native WebSocket with the proxy
  window.WebSocket = WebSocketProxy;
```